# Calculating running totals in JTable using JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, random, jtable, jcombobox

I'm trying to calculate running totals using JTable and Combo combination, sometime it calculate right but on random value selection I get wrong answer.

Here is my code which I'm using to test running totals calculation, any help would be highly appreciated:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.EventObject;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class RunningTotalCalculate extends JFrame {

    public static JTable table = null;
    float sumupValue = 0;
    private MyComboBox cb1, cb2, cb3, cb4, cb5;

    public RunningTotalCalculate() {
        super("Running Total Calculate");

        DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel() {
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                if (column == 0) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
        dm.setDataVector(new Object[][] { { "", "", "" },   { "", "", "" }, { "", "", "" }, 
                { "", "", "" }, { "", "", "" }}, new Object[] { "Combos", "Amount", "Running Total" });

        table = new JTable(dm) {
            public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int col) {
                TableCellRenderer renderer = super.getCellRenderer(row, col);
                int alignment = SwingConstants.RIGHT; // default alignment
                return renderer;
            }
        };

        table.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 14));
        table.setAlignmentX(RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);

        // Arays for cobmos values
        String[] val1 = { "100.00", "200.00", "300.00" };
        String[] val2 = { "-15.00", "-25.00", "35.00" };
        String[] val3 = { "40.00", "-15.00", "10.00" };
        String[] val4 = { "10.00", "35.00", "20.00" };
        String[] val5 = { "-20.00", "-10.00", "15.00" };

        EachRowRenderer rowRenderer = new EachRowRenderer();
        cb1 = new MyComboBox(val1);
        cb2 = new MyComboBox(val2);
        cb3 = new MyComboBox(val3);
        cb4 = new MyComboBox(val4);
        cb5 = new MyComboBox(val5);
        JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox();
        checkBox.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        DefaultCellEditor comboBoxEditor1 = new DefaultCellEditor(cb1);
        DefaultCellEditor comboBoxEditor2 = new DefaultCellEditor(cb2);
        DefaultCellEditor comboBoxEditor3 = new DefaultCellEditor(cb3);
        DefaultCellEditor comboBoxEditor4 = new DefaultCellEditor(cb4);
        DefaultCellEditor comboBoxEditor5 = new DefaultCellEditor(cb5);

        // ItemListener & ActionListener for combo1
        cb1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                fireComboEvent();
            }
        });

        cb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String cbValue1 = (String) cb1.getSelectedItem();
                if (cbValue1 != null) {
                    float value1 = new Float(cbValue1);
                    sumupValue = value1;
                    table.getModel().setValueAt(formatAmount(value1), 0, 1);
                    table.getModel().setValueAt(formatAmount(sumupValue), 0, 2);
                }
            }
        });

        // ItemListener & ActionListener for combo2
        cb2.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                fireComboEvent();
            }
        });

        cb2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String cbValue2 = (String) cb2.getSelectedItem();
                if (cbValue2 != null) {
                    float value2 = new Float(cbValue2);
                    sumupValue = sumupValue + value2;
                    table.getModel().setValueAt(formatAmount(value2), 1, 1);
                    table.getModel().setValueAt(formatAmount(sumupValue), 1, 2);
                }
            }
        });

        // ItemListener & ActionListener for combo3
        cb3.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                fireComboEvent();
            }
        });

        cb3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String cbValue3 = (String) cb3.getSelectedItem();
                if (cbValue3 != null) {
                    float value3 = new Float(cbValue3);
                    sumupValue = sumupValue + value3;
                    table.getModel().setValueAt(formatAmount(value3), 2, 1);
                    table.getModel().setValueAt(formatAmount(sumupValue), 2, 2);
                }
            }
        });

        // ItemListener & ActionListener for combo4
        cb4.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                fireComboEvent();
            }
        });

        cb4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String cbValue4 = (String) cb4.getSelectedItem();
                if (cbValue4 != null) {
                    float value4 = new Float(cbValue4);
                    sumupValue = sumupValue + value4;
                    table.getModel().setValueAt(formatAmount(value4), 3, 1);
                    table.getModel().setValueAt(formatAmount(sumupValue), 3, 2);
                }
            }
        });

        // ItemListener & ActionListener for combo5
        cb5.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                fireComboEvent();
            }
        });

        cb5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String cbValue5 = (String) cb5.getSelectedItem();
                if (cbValue5 != null) {
                    float value5 = new Float(cbValue5);
                    sumupValue = sumupValue + value5;
                    table.getModel().setValueAt(formatAmount(value5), 4, 1);
                    table.getModel().setValueAt(formatAmount(sumupValue), 4, 2);
                }
            }
        });

        EachRowEditor rowEditor = new EachRowEditor(table);
        rowEditor.setEditorAt(0, comboBoxEditor1);
        rowEditor.setEditorAt(1, comboBoxEditor2);
        rowEditor.setEditorAt(2, comboBoxEditor3);
        rowEditor.setEditorAt(3, comboBoxEditor4);
        rowEditor.setEditorAt(4, comboBoxEditor5);

        table.getColumn("Combos").setCellRenderer(rowRenderer);
        table.getColumn("Combos").setCellEditor(rowEditor);

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        getContentPane().add(scroll);
        setSize(400, 160);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static String parseAmount(String val) {
        String retVal = null;
        if (val == null || val.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            val = "0";
        }
        try {
            NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.UK);
            Number parse = format.parse(val);
            retVal = parse.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            retVal = "0";
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    public static String formatAmount(float val) {
        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.UK);
        format.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
        String value = format.format(val);
        return value;
    }


    public class MyComboBox extends JComboBox {

        MyComboBox() {
            super();
        }

        MyComboBox(Object[] v) {
            super(v);
        }

        MyComboBox(Vector v) {
            super(v);
        }

        @Override
        protected void fireActionEvent() {
            super.fireActionEvent();
        }
    }

    public void fireComboEvent() {
        cb1.fireActionEvent();
        cb2.fireActionEvent();
        cb3.fireActionEvent();
        cb4.fireActionEvent();
        cb5.fireActionEvent();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RunningTotalCalculate frame = new RunningTotalCalculate();
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
}

class EachRowRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
  protected Hashtable renderers;

  protected TableCellRenderer renderer, defaultRenderer;

  public EachRowRenderer() {
    renderers = new Hashtable();
    defaultRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
  }

  public void add(int row, TableCellRenderer renderer) {
    renderers.put(new Integer(row), renderer);
  }

  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
      boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    renderer = (TableCellRenderer) renderers.get(new Integer(row));
    if (renderer == null) {
      renderer = defaultRenderer;
    }
    return renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected,
        hasFocus, row, column);
  }
}

class EachRowEditor implements TableCellEditor {
      protected Hashtable editors;

      protected TableCellEditor editor, defaultEditor;

      JTable table;

      public EachRowEditor(JTable table) {
        this.table = table;
        editors = new Hashtable();
        defaultEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(new JTextField());
      }

      public void setEditorAt(int row, TableCellEditor editor) {
        editors.put(new Integer(row), editor);
      }

      public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
          boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        //editor = (TableCellEditor)editors.get(new Integer(row));
        //if (editor == null) {
        //  editor = defaultEditor;
        //}
        return editor.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected,
            row, column);
      }

      public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return editor.getCellEditorValue();
      }

      public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        return editor.stopCellEditing();
      }

      public void cancelCellEditing() {
        editor.cancelCellEditing();
      }

      public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {
        selectEditor((MouseEvent) anEvent);
        return editor.isCellEditable(anEvent);
      }

      public void addCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
        editor.addCellEditorListener(l);
      }

      public void removeCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
        editor.removeCellEditorListener(l);
      }

      public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) {
        selectEditor((MouseEvent) anEvent);
        return editor.shouldSelectCell(anEvent);
      }

      protected void selectEditor(MouseEvent e) {
        int row;
        if (e == null) {
          row = table.getSelectionModel().getAnchorSelectionIndex();
        } else {
          row = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
        }
        editor = (TableCellEditor) editors.get(new Integer(row));
        if (editor == null) {
          editor = defaultEditor;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: What is `EachRowEditor`?

Comment: @trashgod each row editor / rencerere is code [by Nobuo Tamemasa from former Acrionics](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/EachRowwithdifferentEditorExample.htm), unfortunatelly there isn't another free code for that :-)

Comment: @trashgod hmmm and I used this code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6261853/714968)

Comment: @trashgod: `EachRowEditor` & `EachRowRenderer` are Nobuo Tamemasa's code as above reference provided by -mKorbel

Comment: @ArifHameed : Please do explain me what do you mean by `Calculating Running Total`. Explain me, as if I am a child, so that I can understand the picture :-)

Comment: @ArifHameed : I had done till making a model for a `JTable`, tomorrow I will try to add things and try to figure out what to do and how to do things inside `JTable` :-)

Comment: @ArifHameed : If this question is not solved yet, can you provide me `EachRowEditor` and `EachRowRenderer` classes as well, by updating your question :-)

Comment: Sorry guys, couldn't reply to your question as I was away for few days. @Gagandeep Bali: I have added missing classes to my original question. In regard to Running total, the Running total of previous row will be included in the calculation of active row Running total. For instant, when 100 is selected in 1st row, 100 sould be included in Running total of 2nd row and the 2nd row Running total in 3rd row and so on. Last row would have the final value and the each cell in Running total column should be recalculated on changing value of any combo box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please I can't comment something, compare with

[image]

[image]

[image]

from code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.EventObject;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class EachRowTableEditorExample extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTable table;

    public EachRowTableEditorExample() {
        super("EachRow Editor Example");
        try {
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                System.out.println(info.getName());
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            // handle exception
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // handle exception
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // handle exception
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
        DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                int modelColumn = table.convertColumnIndexToModel(column);
                return (modelColumn == 2) ? false : true;
            }
        };
        dm.setDataVector(new Object[][]{
                    {new Double(0), new Integer(2), new Double(0.0)},
                    {new Double(0), new Integer(6), new Double(0.0)},
                    {new Double(0), new Integer(11), new Double(0.0)},
                    {new Double(0), new Integer(5), new Double(0.0)},
                    {new Double(0), new Integer(30), new Double(0.0)}},
                new Object[]{"Combos", "Amount", "Running Total"});
        dm.addTableModelListener(new MyTableModelListener());
        table = new JTable(dm);
        table.setRowHeight(20);
        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.addItem(new Double(0.00));
        comboBox.addItem(new Double(100.00));
        comboBox.addItem(new Double(200.00));
        comboBox.addItem(new Double(300.00));
        JComboBox comboBox1 = new JComboBox();
        comboBox1.addItem(new Double(0.00));
        comboBox1.addItem(new Double(-15.00));
        comboBox1.addItem(new Double(-25.00));
        comboBox1.addItem(new Double(35.00));
        JComboBox comboBox2 = new JComboBox();
        comboBox2.addItem(new Double(0.00));
        comboBox2.addItem(new Double(40.00));
        comboBox2.addItem(new Double(-15.00));
        comboBox2.addItem(new Double(10.00));
        JComboBox comboBox3 = new JComboBox();
        comboBox3.addItem(new Double(0.00));
        comboBox3.addItem(new Double(10.00));
        comboBox3.addItem(new Double(35.00));
        comboBox3.addItem(new Double(20.00));
        JComboBox comboBox4 = new JComboBox();
        comboBox4.addItem(new Double(0.00));
        comboBox4.addItem(new Double(-20.00));
        comboBox4.addItem(new Double(-10.00));
        comboBox4.addItem(new Double(15.00));
        EachRowEditor rowEditor = new EachRowEditor(table);
        rowEditor.setEditorAt(0, new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
        rowEditor.setEditorAt(1, new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox1));
        rowEditor.setEditorAt(2, new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox2));
        rowEditor.setEditorAt(3, new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox3));
        rowEditor.setEditorAt(4, new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox4));
        table.getColumn("Combos").setCellEditor(rowEditor);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        getContentPane().add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setLocation(150, 100);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EachRowTableEditorExample frame = new EachRowTableEditorExample();
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    class MyTableModelListener implements TableModelListener {

        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getSource());
            if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE) {
                int row = e.getFirstRow();
                int column = e.getColumn();
                if (column == 0 || column == 1) {
                    TableModel model = table.getModel();
                    int quantity = ((Integer) model.getValueAt(row, 1)).intValue();
                    double price = ((Double) model.getValueAt(row, 0)).doubleValue();
                    Double value = new Double(quantity * price);
                    model.setValueAt(value, row, 2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class EachRowEditor implements TableCellEditor {

        private Hashtable editors;
        private TableCellEditor editor, defaultEditor;
        private JTable table;

        /**
         * Constructs a EachRowEditor. create default editor
         *
         * @see TableCellEditor
         * @see DefaultCellEditor
         */
        public EachRowEditor(JTable table) {
            this.table = table;
            editors = new Hashtable();
            defaultEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(new JTextField());
        }

        /**
         * @param row
         *            table row
         * @param editor
         *            table cell editor
         */
        public void setEditorAt(int row, TableCellEditor editor) {
            editors.put(new Integer(row), editor);
        }

        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            //editor = (TableCellEditor)editors.get(new Integer(row));
            //if (editor == null) {
            //  editor = defaultEditor;
            //}
            return editor.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected,
                    row, column);
        }

        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return editor.getCellEditorValue();
        }

        public boolean stopCellEditing() {
            return editor.stopCellEditing();
        }

        public void cancelCellEditing() {
            editor.cancelCellEditing();
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {
            selectEditor((MouseEvent) anEvent);
            return editor.isCellEditable(anEvent);
        }

        public void addCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
            editor.addCellEditorListener(l);
        }

        public void removeCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
            editor.removeCellEditorListener(l);
        }

        public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) {
            selectEditor((MouseEvent) anEvent);
            return editor.shouldSelectCell(anEvent);
        }

        protected void selectEditor(MouseEvent e) {
            int row;
            if (e == null) {
                row = table.getSelectionModel().getAnchorSelectionIndex();
            } else {
                row = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
            }
            editor = (TableCellEditor) editors.get(new Integer(row));
            if (editor == null) {
                editor = defaultEditor;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this example. It has given me a clue which might resolve this issue. I think if I could use tableChanged method and perform a loop to recalculate each cell of Running total might resolve this issue. I've not tried yet, but will post the result in next week.

Comment: Here is how I resolved this issue, in case someone is wondering... I took mKorbel example and changed `Running Total` to `Total Amount` and added a new column for `Running Total` in table definition then added a loop to recalculate running total in tableChanged method after `model.setValueAt(value, row, 2);` something like this... `double runningTotal = 0; for (int i = 0; i < table.getModel().getRowCount(); i++) {double amountTotal = ((Double) model.getValueAt(i, 2)).doubleValue();  runningTotal = runningTotal + amountTotal;  model.setValueAt(runningTotal, i, 3);
     }`